# Is there a way to create function template specialization for std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11, std

I have a function template

```
template<typename T>
void output(T& value)
{
}
```

Is there a way to create specialization for output std::array objects? Yes, I know, that arrays of different sizes are different types. ) I just hope that there is a way in c++11

Comment: ¤ Technically what you're after is an overload. It just goes like `template< class T, int n > void output( std::array<T, n> const& a ) { blah }`. You could make it much more general by instead offering a version taking two iterators, possibly bundled in one thingy. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Did you really mean to write `T&` so that the function cannot be called with a `T const` or rvalue, or should that rather be `T const&`?

Comment: @Alf: what makes you think that the template as written cannot be instantiated with a const-qualified type as `T`? Argument deduction from an rvalue causes problems here, you'd have to write `foo<const int>(1);`, but argument deduction from a `T const` doesn't: `const int i = 1; foo(i);`.

Comment: @Steve: i just don't see the point in adding academically proof sufficient weasel language for such questions. for example, `output<double>( 3 )` won't work. i suspect you know that. oh, i read the rest of what you wrote. you did know that. so your comment was just meaningless pedantry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specialize it for all arrays, that would require a "partial specialization" of the template. A full specialization of a template pins down the values of all template parameters (in this case there is only one, `T`, so a full specialization only covers one type in place of `T`). A partial specialization covers multiple possible values of the template parameters (in this case we want to cover any `std::array<U,N>` in place of `T`), so a partial specialization has template parameters of its own.

C++ permits partial specialization of class templates but not of function templates.

Instead, you can overload it. You define another function template with the same name and different parameters:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void output (const std::array<T,N> &arr); // I guess "const" by the function name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class T, unsigned N>
void output(std::array<T,N>& value){
}
```

Would be what you *should* be using, since specializations are discouraged. Moreover, you can't partially specialize function templates.

Comment: `class N` <- That's a typo, I guess?

Comment: I think it would be nice to add `const`.

Answer (score 1):

You need an [overload](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm), not a specialization (there's just full specialization for function templates).

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void output (std::array<T,N> &arr);
```

You are not allowed to put it into `namespace std` though. And if it just outputs data, you should not pass a non-const reference.

However, go the route the standard library goes, and use iterators instead:

```
template <typename Iter>
void output (Iter it, Iter end)
```

This makes your function flexible w.r.t. the container type: It probably does not need to know whether it's a `list`, `deque` or an `array`.

Comment: Like @Alf says, technically this is an overload. That's why you can't do so in `namespace std`.